# issue in using templates in xcode for c++

Tags: c++, xcode, templates

I am trying to use templates in xcode but I keep on getting the error
"Expected unqualified -id" wherever I write `<template class T>` or `<template typename T>`

I even tried a bare bones program to test the issue-

```
<template typename T>
void Print(T &x)
{
    cout<<"Printing-"<<x<<endl;

}
```

but again I got the error on the first line.
Any advice as to how to fix the issue?

Comment: template <typename T>

Comment: Arghh ! sorry man , had slipped through my mind , thanks :)